# Reading parameters in file upload in cordova android using php

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova

I am trying to implement file upload/download using this plugin(https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md). But i am failed to read the parameters(ie filename,mimetype) from the url.Here is the javascript code

```
//paramters for upload file
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
             options.fileKey = "file";
             options.fileName = uri.substr(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
             options.mimeType = "text/plain";
```

upload url

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
         ft.upload(uri, encodeURI('http://192.168.43.211/insiderapp/insiderapp_backend.php?action=uploadfile'), win, fail, options);
```

`win` and `fail` are success and error callback functions
actual problem is i can't get **options** in php file.
here is my php

```
function uploadFile(){
    //get the parameters
    $options=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    echo $options->fileKey;
}
```

It will returns `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer.Simply read `$_FILES` array contain all the data

```
if ($_FILES) {  
    print_r($_FILES);

    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }
```